# How can I make cut take less time to process?

Tags: bash, macos, cut

I have a text file with a whole bunch of lines (1000 exactly) and they all have 4 bits of text, seperated by a `;`.

Here is the for loop I'm using, to go through each line:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    let liner++
    if [[ liner -eq "1" ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    name=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d';' -f1)
    fullname=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d';' -f2)
    id=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d';' -f3)
    test=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d';' -f4)

    echo "${GREEN}$(($liner-1))) ${name} ${ORANGE}v${test} ${RED}(${id})${NC}"
    stuff+=("${fullname}")
done < list.txt
```

It takes about 5 seconds before it finishes running and I believe it's from all those cut (name, fullname, id, test) variables. What would be the best solution to speed this up?

Comment: research awk and it's `-v "var=$var"` feature for yourr  `$GREEN} ${RED} ${ORANGE}`, then `awk -v ... {print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4}' file`  . Good luck.

Comment: Could you send me a better example please?

Comment: I'm looking into awk and your `awk -v ... {print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4}' file` is making no sense to me

Comment: leave out the `-v ...` and see if you like the basic output. Then you can start adding things. Good luck.

Comment: Avoid calling shell utilities inside a loop in bash. Much less calling `cut` 4-times every iteration and creating 4-pipes. Instead look into bash built-ins (parameter expansions) for string manipulation. Learning awk is worth every minute spent. Beyond what you can do will shell built-ins, awk will be orders of magnitude faster. See [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) for a good reference. There are many tutorials out there too.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #1: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), especially the second on field splitting.

Comment: Ok I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk undoubtedly provides a better solution, but if you don't want to learn Awk right now, you could speed your function up a lot by just using `read` to split the lines into fields:

```bash
liner=0
stuff=()
while IFS=\; read -r name fullname id test; do
    echo "$GREEN$((++liner))) $name ${ORANGE}v$test $RED($id)$NC"
    stuff+=("$fullname")
done < <(tail -n+2 1000num.txt)
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this but it didn't seem to work for me. It kept saying: `syntax error near unexpected token '<'`

Comment: @heyhoo: if you're not using bash, don't tag your questions with [tag:bash]. It's misleading.